# What does "the halls of learning" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> “Now, now, Viktor!” said Karkaroff with a laugh that didn't reach his cold eyes, “don't go giving away anything else, now, or your charming friend will know exactly where to find us!”
>
> Dumbledore smiled, his eyes twinkling. “Igor, all this secrecy, one
>   would almost think you didn't want visitors.”
>
> “Well, Dumbledore,” said Karkaroff, displaying his yellowing teeth to
>   their fullest extent, “we are all protective of our private domains,
>   are we not? Do we not jealously guard **the halls of learning** that have
>   been entrusted to us? Are we not right to be proud that we alone know
>   our school's secrets, and right to protect them?”

I don't quite understand the phrase "*the halls of learning*" in this context. Does it simply mean: *learning something in the halls*? What does it mean exactly?

Comment: Compare "the Halls of Academe".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Halls of learning* is a somewhat archaic idiom referring to a school or university. **Hall** in this context would simply mean a large room or building, like the Great Hall at Hogwarts.